# Насколько правильно использовать мой подход передачи значения переменной из js в переменную php

Tags: php, javascript

Добрый день знатоки!=)

Вообщем смотрел кучу материалов на счет передачи переменной 
из js / jqwery в PHP , во всех этих материалах объяснялось, что это не самая тривиальная задача, куча строк кода приводилось в пример, через метод $_GET например( или вообще дикие какие-то методы, библиотеки, строк 25-100 кода) ...

И сегодня, в 3:30 утра, сидя за решением очередной задачки, кокраз с этим связанной, и выпив пару бутылочек вкусного пива, меня "осенило" -

зачем писать весь этот не нужный код из примеров, когда все можно сделать настолько просто, что сам себе не поверил что вообще сработает. Короче закралось сомнение что вообще это получится, но как оказалось все гениальное просто...
Вот привожу код собственно того, что мне пришло в голову:

```
<script>
var peremennayaJs= 1;
<?$peremennayaPhp="peremennayaJs";?>;
alert(<?echo $peremennayaPhp;?>);
</script>
```

Я был сильно удивлен, что это сработало- изначально думал скептически, что это приход в пьяном угаре, но нет...

Вот закралось сомнение- может все же я что-то упустил из виду, может так делать нельзя по каким-то не явным причинам. 
Просто я программирую можно сказать первый месяц, и то только процедурное программирование на PHP, c js  только начинаю смотреть простейшие вещи.

Прошу не закидывать камнями в случае если это банально- и я сейчас поделился тем, что всем известно как 2+2... Просто тогда зачем всех вводят в заблуждение, что передача значения переменной js в php это ппц как сложно?!

В общем вопрос- насколько это допустимо? Можно ли этим пользоваться, есть ли какие-то подводные камни?

Comment: Костян, у тебя на выходе в alert вылазиет `var peremennayaJs=1` а не с php. Сейчас напишу в ответе подробно почему так происходит

Comment: Проверяю в денвере. Мне в алерт выпадает кокраз единица( в гугл хром и firefox). Суть не в том что в алерт выпадает- а втом что значение передалось переменной php, разве нет?!

Comment: Для передачи переменных нужно использовать запросы или оставлять значения в атрибутах тегов

Comment: Не холивара ради, имхо, использовать в 16 году денвер, это моветон.

Comment: Поражают меня ребята, которые минусуют вопрос, если для них он кажется простым и очевидным. Вопрос вполне разложен и подробно описан хоть с излишками

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак в html документе мы имеем код

```
<script>
    var peremennayaJs = 1;
    <?php $peremennayaPhp = "peremennayaJs"; ?>
    alert(<?php echo $peremennayaPhp; ?>);
</script>
```

После построения документа `$peremennayaPhp` несёт в себе (string)`"peremennayaJs"`, а не значение из `var peremennayaJs`. В итоге выходит такая функция `alert(peremennayaJs)`, она и выводит `1`

Comment: Да! Это я дал маху- поспешил обрадоваться... Только до самого дошло, что в итоге сделал...

Comment: @Константин, всякое бывает :)

Comment: Хорошо. Отсюда вопрос- есть ли метод в js  наподобия echo в php? Тоесть- $peremennayaPhp = <script>"echo" peremennayaJs</script>

Comment: @Константин, для передачи на сервер без запросов никак

Comment: @Константин, у меня получилась функция в js на 16 строк, которая отправляет запросы с callback'ами и даёт возможность отправлять хоть десятки запросов одновременно лишь одной строчкой. Какие проблемы написать такую функцию самостоятельно?